# c# web service not returning results

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services, webmethod

I recently "finished" a new project except there is a small problem. Im not getting my results back.

This project utilizes c# web services via a SOAP client along with Request and Response Classes. The project is designed to reserve something, in this demo, it reserves a seat in a cinema. However when the data is passed from the windows form client to the web service, nothing comes back. I recently stopped the project from freezing upon execution of the web method.

This is the method that calls the web service (The method signature is only temporary)

```
public void derp()
{
    var client = new SampleServiceSoapClient();
    var req = new GetReservationRequest();
    req.row = row;
    req.seat = seat;
    req.name = textNameRequest.Text;
    try
    {
        client.GetReservation(req);
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Server Unavailable");
    }
}
```

I am running this method on a seperate thread to stop crashing. The output of this method is supposed to come back through a response object and then i assign the values of said object to text boxes on the form. However, the data is lost before it returns.

The web method is as follows

```
[WebMethod]
public GetReservationResponse GetReservation(GetReservationRequest req)
{
    object o = HttpContext.Current.Cache["Reservation"];
    if(o == null)
    {
        o = reservedSeat;
    }
    else
    {
        reservedSeat = (bool[,])o;
    }

    GetReservationResponse resp = new GetReservationResponse();
    string rowHolder = "A";
    int rowRequest = req.row;
    int seatCopy = 0;

    bool emptySeat = false;
    while (rowRequest < 12)
    {
        for (int seat = req.seat; seat < 16; seat++)
        {
            if (reservedSeat[req.row, seat])
            {
             //Loop back
            }
            else
            {
                emptySeat = true;
                seatCopy = seat;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (reservedSeat[req.row, 15])
        {
            seatCopy = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    switch (rowRequest)
    {
        case 1: rowHolder = "A";
            break;
        case 2: rowHolder = "B";
            break;
        case 3: rowHolder = "C";
            break;
        case 4: rowHolder = "D";
            break;
        case 5: rowHolder = "E";
            break;
        case 6: rowHolder = "F";
            break;
        case 7: rowHolder = "G";
            break;
        case 8: rowHolder = "H";
            break;
        case 9: rowHolder = "I";
            break;
        case 10: rowHolder = "J";
            break;
        case 11: rowHolder = "K";
            break;
        case 12: rowHolder = "L";
            break;
        default: rowHolder = "None Specified";
            break;
    }
    int x = 0;
    if (!reservedSeat[rowRequest, seatCopy])
    {
        reservedSeat[rowRequest, seatCopy] = true;
        seatCopy++;
        //resp.row = rowRequest;
        x = seatCopy;
        seatCopy--;
        if (seatCopy.Equals(15))
        {
            rowRequest++;
        }
    }
    resp.row = rowHolder;
    resp.seat = x;   
    //row++            
    return resp;
}
```

I have no clue why the data is being lost before it comes back but some information would be amazing...

Comment: Have your tried to assign a response variable to see if you are getting data back? eg, 'var response = client.GetReservation(req);'? Also, have you tried fiddler or wireshark to make sure the request and response are as expected?

Comment: It looks like you are not saving the response. For testing your web service outside your code, try using Web Service Studio or SOAPUI.

Comment: @layoric that was my next step. Also idk what fiddler and wireshark are. Raymond i dont know what those are either lol

Answer (score 0):

Where in this code rowrequest is incremented? It seems to me, that you have infinite loop here:

```
        while (rowRequest < 12)
        {
                for (int seat = req.seat; seat < 16; seat++)
                {
                    if (reservedSeat[req.row, seat])
                    {
                    //Loop back
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        emptySeat = true;
                        seatCopy = seat;
                        break;
                    }
            }
            if (reservedSeat[req.row, 15])
            {
                seatCopy = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: `if (seatCopy.Equals(15))
                    {
                        rowRequest++;
                    }`

Comment: It is out of while. So this code is not run inside infinite loop and cannot break it. And symptoms is similar to infinite loop too.

Comment: RowRequest is the value pulled from the client. Similar to req.row but stored seperately to maintain scope. The loop executes until an empty seat is found then it terminates and the values are passed to external values outside of the for loop's scope